# Do I need to register all the model class in hibernate config file

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

Suppose I have number of model classes(Entity class). Do I need to register all the model class in hibernate config file one after another like

```
...
<mapping class="com.java.ent.Table"/>
...
```

or any annotation is there which marks as entity? For medium app there would be huge amount of table and its corresponding model entity. how to manage it?

Comment: I don't know Hibernate well. The question is whether you are willing to use JPA which is implemented by Hibernate; in that case you don't need to list all your classes. This way is also **highly** recommended in Hibernate documenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There another way to configure hibernate sessionFactory where you can actually give only packageToScan.

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop><!-- added -->
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop><!-- added -->
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop><!-- added -->

            </props>
        </property>

        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.web.entities</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own set package in AnnotationConfiguration as described in the dicumentation.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/ch01.html

Or

Another option is to write custom AnnotationConfigurationWithWildcard which extends the org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration and inject as spring dependency.

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configurationClass" value="org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfigurationWithWildcard"/>
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
</bean>
```

You can use which ever suits you better.

Comment: but I have to anyway register entity in hibernate.cfg.xml as I mention. Any way without it is there i mean any annotation?

Comment: If I am getting your question correct, with the above solution you just have to give the package where your all entities are located and hibernate will pick all the annotated entities. In the second approach you can simply add one line with wild card like <mapping class="com.*"/> in hibernate.cfg. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: with AnnotationConfigurationWithWildcard I am getting class is not found excp...with <mapping class="com.*"/> also same excp. i am using Hibernate4